# How can I run 'screen' without it being attached to a terminal so that I can capture the output in a C++ (qt) app?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, gnu-screen

I'm currently displaying serial output from my embedded device in a Mac OS terminal using the command

```
screen /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200
```

Instead of displaying the output in the terminal, I'd like to be able to read it line by line in my C++ (qt) app so I can process it and display it in a GUI.

I tried to create a QProcess object to run the screen command above, but screen fails, saying "Must be connected to a terminal".

Is there a way I can "fake" the connectedness to a terminal so that the QProcess will be able to successfully run the screen command? I don't need to input any commands, I just need to capture the output that the embedded device is writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [boost serial port](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html) to read the incoming data. Be aware that this will have to be done in a thread or using [Qt Concurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html). From this thread you can send [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) that connected to the correct slots of your data display will take the data and display it. However, Qt also provides a serial port class that you can use: [QSerialPort](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html). I would recomend using [QTextEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) as your display widget and [QTextEdit::append](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append) for your slot.